# How can I optimize my function that uses a nested for loop in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to create a program that compares a sub sequence of nodes with a sequence of nodes to see how often the sub sequence appears in each sequence to about 80% correctness. To do this I put together the function below:

```
code = c(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
subs = c("A", "C","D")
n = length(code)
m = length(subs)
mat = matrix(0, n+1, m+1)
for(i in 1:(n+1)){
  for(j in 1:(m+1)){
    previ = i - 1
    prevj = j - 1
    if(previ!=0 & prevj!=0){
      if(code[[previ]] == subs[[prevj]]){
        mat[i,j] = mat[previ,prevj] + 1
      }
      else{
        mat[i,j] = max(mat[previ,j], mat[i,prevj])
      }
    }
  }
}
print(mat)
return(mat[n+1,m+1])
```

But it is very slow when it is used on the larger data set I'm working with. Is there a way to optimize this loop code or do this analysis without a loop?

Comment: R is optimized to be fast on vector operations, so I would create functions and apply those functions on the vectors.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I'm sorry I have to ask this but can you give an example?

Comment: Can you clarify your goal, "compares a sub sequence of nodes with a sequence of nodes to see how often the sub sequence appears in each sequence"? This sounds like you just want a count of how often `"A"`, `"C"`, and `"D"` each appear in `code`, but your output is obviously more complex than that.

Comment: In your `code` vector, is `c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")` a single "sequence", or is each of `"A"`, `"B"`, etc considered a "sequence"? Likewise with `subs`.

Comment: @zephryl I am trying to find the longest common subsequence . `code` is a single sequence and `subs` is a single sub-sequence. I'm trying to score how often a subsequence appears in thousands of codes. I hope this helps.

Comment: But the sub-sequence A-C-D doesn't appear at all in the sequence A-B-C-D-E, so shouldn't the result just be `0`? Why is the result a 6 x 4 matrix rather than just a single value?

Comment: Maybe a better way to say what the code should be doing is returning the length of the longest common subsequence between `code` and `subs`. You're right that A-C-D doesn't appear directly, but it does appear in the right order with some codes in between. That's the reason for the matrix, since it compares each element in `code` with each element of `subs` and adds 1 to the current element if it equals and if it doesn't it checks the element to left and above it to see which one is greater and sets it as the current element.

Comment: Yeah, @Isaac. If you wanted to apply a function that checked each element against a vector, it might look like this `check_element <- function(e) {if (a %in% vec) {return True} else {return False}}`. Then you would just do an apply on the list `list.lapply(check_element)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about exact matches:

- convert `code` and `subs` to strings like this:

```
code_string = paste(code, collapse = '')
```

(similar with subs_string)

- use {stringr} to find the matches:

```
library(stringr)
str_locate_all(string = 'ABCXABCABC', pattern = 'ABC')
```

```
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1   3
[2,]     5   7
```

If you want to allow a certain amount of deviation, you can:

- split the `codestring` into successive segments of `frame_size` length (e. g. length 4 when looking for a 3-letter pattern):

```
frame_size = 4
nc = nchar(code_string)

fragments <- substring(code_string,
                       1:(nc - frame_size + 1),
                       frame_size:nc
                       )
```

```
> fragments
[1] "ABCD" "BCDE"
```

- use the Levenshtein distance (dissimilarity) between each fragment and your pattern:

```
library(comparator)

fragments |> 
  ## `Map` = do this for each item of fragments
  Map(f = \(fragment){ifelse(grepl(subs_string, fragment),
                             ## return 0 for exact match:
                             0,
                             ## penalize insertion or substitution of letters
                             ## in `fragment` for later filtering:
                             Levenshtein(insertion = 100,
                                         deletion = 1,
                                         substitution = 100
                                         )(fragment, subs_string)
                             )
  }
)
```

output:

```
$ABCD
[1] 1 ## this score is OK, we only need to delete one letter from 'ABCD'
      ## to match 'ABD'

$BCDE
[1] 101 ## this score tells us that a letter has been inserted and/or
        ## substituted from 'BCDE' which we don't want
```

- now you can filter the output for scores < 2 (max. one deletion from a 4-letter string to match your 3-letter string; that's your 80% similarity)